# I turn wildfly into a service and try to use systemctl to start it, but it exit right away

Tags: java, wildfly

I copy wildfly.service to /etc/systemd/system/ ,wildfly.conf to /etc/wildlfy/, launch.sh to wildfly/bin
but when i try to use systemctl start wildfly to start the service
the service quit right away.
here is the message:

```
○ wildfly.service - The WildFly Application Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wildfly.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2022-09-28 02:08:05 UTC; 10s ago
    Process: 3549 ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3549 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 49ms

Sep 28 02:08:05 test4 systemd[1]: Started The WildFly Application Server.
Sep 28 02:08:05 test4 systemd[1]: wildfly.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

When I directly execute /opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh,the wildly could be started and I can visit the index page.
here is the wildfly.service

```
[Unit]
Description=The WildFly Application Server
After=syslog.target network.target
Before=httpd.service

[Service]
Environment=LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND=1
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/wildfly/wildfly.conf
LimitNOFILE=102642
PIDFile=/run/wildfly/wildfly.pid
ExecStart=/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh $WILDFLY_MODE $WILDFLY_CONFIG $WILDFLY_BIND
StandardOutput=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What can I do to fix it

Comment: Is `/opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh` executable?

Comment: Typo in "EnvironmentFile" (minus in front of the path) ?

Comment: Verify the output of "systemctl status wildfly.service", may be you can get some usefull information there.